# citation appear as [?] - using IEEEtran

Tags: bibliographies

Why does my citation appear as [?]. This is the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % The IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi

\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\newcommand\MYhyperrefoptions{bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,
pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true,
colorlinks=true,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black},urlcolor={black},
pdftitle={Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Computer Society Journals},%<!CHANGE!
pdfsubject={Typesetting},%<!CHANGE!
pdfauthor={Michael D. Shell},%<!CHANGE!
pdfkeywords={Computer Society, IEEEtran, journal, LaTeX, paper,
             template}}%<^!CHANGE!

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\begin{document}
\title{x}

\author{}

% The paper headers
\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~14, No.~8, August~2015}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Advanced Demo of IEEEtran.cls for IEEE Computer Society Journals}

\maketitle
\IEEEdisplaynontitleabstractindextext
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle


\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
\IEEEraisesectionheading{\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}}
\else
\fi

\cite{cao2020long}

\bibliography{references/human_pose_forecasting}

\end{document}
```

And this is my citation in the file

```
@inproceedings{cao2020long,
  title={Long-term human motion prediction with scene context},
  author={Cao, Zhe and Gao, Hang and Mangalam, Karttikeya and Cai, Qi-Zhi and Vo, Minh and Malik, Jitendra},
  booktitle={Computer Vision--ECCV 2020: 16th European Conference, Glasgow, UK, August 23--28, 2020, Proceedings, Part I 16},
  pages={387--404},
  year={2020},
  organization={Springer}
}
```

it says

```
Citation `cao2020long' on page 1 undefined on input line 40.
```

You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.

```
There were undefined references.
```

You have referenced something which has not yet been labelled. If you have labelled it already, make sure that what is written inside \ref{...} is the same as what is written inside \label{...}.

Comment: What you've shown looks ok to me, what does the bibtex log (the `.blg` file) say? Quite possibly another entry in your bib file is malformed and causing an error.

Comment: @DaiBowen i have updated my post

Comment: Are you running bibtex? What does the bibtex log say? This can be found in the `.blg` file rather than the `.log` file.

Comment: @DaiBowen i am using overleaf. You can try paste the whole thing into overleaf.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number) The `.blg` file generated gives a clear error `I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file output.aux`.